# Where should I add my @escape parameter?

Tags: swift

```
public func promisedGET<T: YumiInitializableFromJSON>(
              _ path: String,
              parameters: Alamofire.Parameters? = nil) -> Promise<T> {
    return Promise { (fulfill, reject) in
        self.GET(path, parameters: parameters) {
            result in result.propagate(toFulfillment: fulfill, rejection: reject)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error

> Closure use of non-escaping parameter ‘fulfill’ may allow it to escape

It's been hours I am reading about @escape parameter but I can't manage to find out where to include it nor if it is the reason why I get this error. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: What does the function `result.propogate` look like. And what is `fulfilled` defined as? i.e. what is the `T` in `Promise<T>`.

Comment: `@escaping` should be put on the first parameter of the closure passed to initializer of the `Promise` type

Comment: @CalebKleveter I am getting the error on the return line.

Comment: I would follow @MilanNosáľ's advice and let us know what the result is.